# Need Help Designing Tennis Ladder Database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm creating a tennis ladder website using PHP/MySQL/CSS & HTML.  A tennis ladder is basically a system where you challenge a player and if you beat them you go one spot above them on the ladder rankings list.  Originally I designed the website so that it was a single ladder that users could register to join and then participate in.  That was up and running fairly well (in tests), but now I've decided I want to further expand it to allow multiple ladders.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- A user can join many different ladders.
- A ladder can have many different users.
- Each ladder has a type, name, and description.
- A ladder match will keep record of who won, who lost, and the score and date played of the match.
- Stats will be collected for each player within that SPECIFIC ladder.

Here's what the tables for the ladder DB look like:

[image: Table diagram]

Here's a rudimentary visual representation of what some test data would look like when displayed.  This will change to represent a select ladder's data.

[image: UI Mockup]

This is the first real web app I've attempted, so any advice on schema structure would be appreciated.  Originally when I had conceived of it as just 1 ladder that everyone could join I had combined the `User` table fields with the `UserLadderStats` fields, and there were no Ladder or Ladder_Users tables.  `LadderMatch` table has remained almost the same, but it now has foreign key references.

Comment: You can probably use just one table for the purpose of Ladder_users and UserLaderStats. They both contain the (UserID, LadderID) pair; having two tables might be redundant.

Comment: Good luck with your db work, but please check some better than your pre-Elo-ladder solution for your ranking system. :) - Here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison) between *Elo*, *Glicko*, *TrueSkill* and *ree* rating system.

Comment: Thanks, I plan on introducing different ranking systems a bit down the line.  This is my first attempt at creating a web app -- I've only had one programming class in my life, so all of this PHP/SQL/HTML/CSS/Javascript stuff is still fairly new to me.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good, except I would combine the Ladder_Users table with the UserLadderStats table. There's no reason to have them separate and it just introduces the chance for data integrity problems. Just move all the stats onto the Ladder_Users, and then you can drop UserLadderStats.

Also, note that the WinnerUserID and LoserUserID in LadderMatch are foreign keys, even though they aren't explicitly marked as such.

Comment: Thank you -- not sure why I didn't think to do that before.